# sys.dm_exec_query_stats column descriptions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Does anyone know the definitions for all the columns returned by sys.dm_exec_query_stats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx